# OrientDB Teleporter - Pull only selected columns for Vertex from RDBMS

Tags: orientdb, rdbms

I am trying to pull data from `Oracle RDBMS` and move it to `OrientDB` using `teleporter`. My relational database have multiple columns and have E-R relationships maintained. I have two questions :

1. My objective is to get only few columns ( that holds unique identity and foreign key relations ) and not all bulky column data. Is there any configuration using which I could do so. Today include and exclude only works at full DB table level.
2. Another objective is to keep my graph db sync with these selected table-column data which I pushed in previous run. Additional data which comes to RDBMS I would want in my graph db too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enjoy this feature, and more others, in orientdb 3.0 through a JSON configuration, but there is not any documentation about it yet. Currently in 2.2.x you can just configure relationships and edges as described here:

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Teleporter-Import-Configuration.html

In the next 2 weeks all these features will be available also in 2.2.x and well documented in order to make the comprehension of the config very easy.

At the moment you can adopt the following workaround:

- import all the columns for each table in the correspondent vertex as usual.
- drop the properties you are not interested in after each sync. You could write down a script where you call the teleporter execution and then delete the properties you don't care about from the schema.

I will update here when the alignment with 3.0 and the doc will be complete.

Comment: Additionally can you please help me with any sample sync script available on docs or github which I could refer to write my migration. I have used direct oteleporter with command line params so far. Here if we have new + old data in RDBMS tables and retry same teleporter command it throws lot of errors however it do insert new one. Is there any remedy or graceful way to handle it.